# Jstatd connection issues

Tags: vmware, visualvm, jstatd

Having a little trouble connecting jstatd with visualvm. Below is a break down of my settings:

**jstatd.policy**

```
grant codebase "file:/usr/java/jre1.7.0/lib/tools.jar" {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

**Called With**

```
jstatd -p 9999 -J-Djava.security.policy=/usr/java/jre1.7.0/bin/jstatd.policy
```

**Pulling Ports**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43786           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22846/jstatd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22846/jstatd
```

**And Ports Nice and Open**

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:9999
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:43786
```

The application being run is sat on vmware, although application can be accessed with no issues.

If anyone has any ideas on connecting to visualvm it would be great.

Comment: How did you try to connect to remote host from VisualVM? Can you summarize your steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you need to start jstatd with host IP addr parameter, like this:
jstatd -p 9999 -J-Djava.security.policy=/usr/java/jre1.7.0/bin/jstatd.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.0.123

192.168.0.123 - change this IP with your IP address of remote server

Check this link: http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2012/01/troubleshooting-visualvm-remote.html

Comment: thank you, thank you, thanks you. This has been bugging me for ages.